# How can I encrypt all my internal drives on install and mount them at start?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, encryption

I have more than one physical hard drive in my computer and I want to encrypt them all on a new installation of 16.04, so that no data can be read from outside the operating system.

However, it is important to me that they still function like unencrypted drives when Ubuntu is started and my user account is logged in. (That means, not having to mount and unlock them constantly, but rather on system start like an encrypted home folder or crypt-swap.)

What would be the best way to do this?

*Edit:*

Since it is possible to encrypt the system drive at installation and have it unlocked at the splash screen, I guess the only thing left would be to encrypt all other drives individually (which can be done with the GNOME Disk Utility and then add the decryption information to the keyfile that is called to unlock the system drive somehow. Then, all drives would be decrypted at start. Unfortunately, I don't know how the backend of this system works at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest VeraCrypt.  VeraCrypt is a port of TrueCrypt but is still maintained.  It uses substantially stronger encryption than TrueCrypt ever did.  You can download VeraCrypt [here](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Downloads).

For your stated purpose, you're going to want the command-line version, so install that.  Then you'll want to encrypt with a long and impossible-to-remember randomized passphrase.  Let's say that's "Olei1ahFNooyae1Goot."  Now write a startup script that invokes

> veracrypt --password=Olei1ahFNooyae1Goot /dev/sdx /mnt/point1

replacing /dev/sdx with the actual device names and of course /mnt/point1 with your desired mount points.

Of course the passphrase you pick (Olei1ahFNooyae1Goot) will only exist on the encrypted system volume, so it cannot be exposed.

That's how I'd do this, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I would really like to accomplish this without third-party software, although VeraCrypt seems rather trustworthy from what I have read so far. The point of this question was actually that the system drive is already unlocked at the splash screen with a password and it would probably only be necessary to add all other encrypted drives to the keyfile that is executed on start, which would allow to accomplish this without installing anything new.